# Taking a picture with 2 secs of delay

Tags: android, camera

Is there a way to take a picture two seconds after the Camera.takePicture method is invoked? For some reason, I do not want to use handler/timer to schedule the invocation of takePicture.

Precisely, I would like to use **a different solution** than the following one:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    <here takePicture is invoked>
                }
            });
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: use a handler for this purpose

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan for your reply but I do not want to use handler directly. I've modified a bit my question.

Comment: Why do you want to use a different solution?

Comment: @npace, because my app crashes and I do not know why so I am experimenting other solutions. My app takes pictures at regular intervals (30 sec) using AlarmManager. I would like that 2 sec before the picture is taken, a sound is played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `AlarmManager` with a `PendingIntent` and handle taking the camera capture in your `Activity.onNewIntent` method, but it is a very confusing solution for what you are trying to solve (a much better use of `AlarmManager` is to schedule tasks so that they are performed even if the user exits your application). This solution also requires more code and is less precise/reliable and less efficient than using a `Handler`.

EDIT: You can also use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` along with a `Runnable`.

(Personal opinion following) If you are exploring the APIs available in Android for performing timed tasks, that is ok, but  I wouldn't use `AlarmManager` to schedule timed tasks within an `Activity` that's already running.

If you just want to have the code a bit more organised, you can make an inner class that implements `Runnable` and schedule your action like this:

```
class MyCameraActivity extends Activity
{
    class TakePictureTask implements Runnable
    {
         public void run()
         {
             MyCameraActivity.this.takePicture();
         }
    }

    void scheduleCameraShot()
    {
        (new Handler(this.getMainLooper())).postDelayed(new TakePictureTask(), 2000);
    }
}
```